# É possivel verificar o tamanho de uma string que está dentro de um array?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um *array* que é construido pelos resultados das *chekbox* selecionadas...

Ele retorna com um `var_dump`:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "BXT0022" [1]=> string(7) "BXT0010" [2]=> string(7) "BXT0024" }
```

Eu só quero *chekar* se tem algo no *array* ou se ele está vazia, mas não estou conseguindo porque se não tiver nada selecionado ela retorna isto:

```
string(0) ""
```

Como posso fazer um if (não tem nada no *array*) faz o implode... Tentei com o `count` do *array* mas dá sempre 1 mesmo sem nada escolhido , `issset` também tem lá algo e não funciona... Não sei o que mais usar...

Tem jeito de *chekar* o comprimento da string que o *array* retorna?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`empty`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php):

```
if(empty($variavel)) { ...
```

Ele retorna `true` tanto para strings vazias, quanto para arrays vazias.

Comment: Valeu era isso que me faltava ...muito obrigado

Comment: @user7385, marque essa resposta como aceita.

Comment: Você quer dizer: "ele retorna `true`", certo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Ops, isso

Answer (score 1):

Ao utilizar implode num array vazio vai dar 1 porque o array inicia na posição 0 então vc tem q diminuir 1 da variável q conta o tamanho do array

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen($variavel) > 0)
```

Vai verifica quantos caracteres tem a string passada, se for maior que 0, é por que tem algo

Mas pode ser usado varios:

```
if(!isset($variavel))
if($variavel != "")
if($variavel != NULL)
if($variavel[1]) - uma string pode ser usada como array sem ter que fazer ela ser um array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o strlen (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php) para saber se a stringé maior que 0.

O isset apenas vai dizer se a variável foi iniciada, que nesse caso foi, poré, foi iniciado vazia.

Abs